# Ошибка в PHP [object Object]

Tags: php, javascript, json, phpmyadmin

Помогите , мне нужно что бы вывело пароль на моём сайте , но выводит `[object Object]`

код PHP:

```
$sqlch = "SELECT 'password' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = '$login'";
$resch = mysqli_query($mysql_con, $sqlch);
$rowch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch);
echo json_encode($rowch);`
```

Код JS:

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
response = JSON.parse(response); 
alert(response);`
```

Comment: в пхп не шарю, но попробуйте `alert(response.password);`

Comment: Огромное спасибо !

Comment: незачто, а вообще в таких случаях выводите обьект в консоль и смотрите на его структуру